# Scala method type-parameter specification for returning various numeric types

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand scala type parameters and having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to do conversions.

Suppose I'm modeling tic-tac-toe:

```
sealed trait Side {

  def toChar   : Char
  def toInt    : Int
  def toDouble : Double = toInt.toDouble

}//end trait Side

case object X extends Side {
  override val toChar = 'X'
  override val toInt = -1
}//end case object X extends Side

case object O extends Side {
  override val toChar = 'O'
  override val toInt = 1
}//end case object O extends Side

case object EMPTY extends Side {
  override val toChar = '*'
  override val toInt = 0
}
```

I then model a tic tac board in a way that both naturally represents the game and also can be converted to a numeric array that is useful with machine learning techniques.

```
class Board(val rows : Int = 3, 
            val cols : Int = 3, 
            val repr : Array[Array[Side]] = Array.ofDim[Side](3,3)) {

  def flatten : Array[Side] = repr.flatten

  /**
   * Converts this board into a 1-D numeric array.  This is likely the 
   * incorrect method signature.
   */
  def flattenNumeric[T] : Array[T] = ???

}
```

My question is: how do I replace the `???`?

I would like to be able to make calls of the form

```
val board = new Board

board.flattenNumeric[Int] //returns Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
board.flattenNumeric[Double] //returns Array(0.0, 0.0, ...)
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only two type parameters you need this to work with, I'd suggest just writing separate `flattenInt` and `flattenDouble` methods—it's much simpler and clearer. That's not an answer to your question, though, so if you really want this to be generic, the standard Scala way would be to use a [type class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) like this:

```
class Board(val rows: Int = 3, 
            val cols: Int = 3, 
            val repr: Array[Array[Side]] = Array.ofDim[Side](3,3)) {

  def flatten: Array[Side] = repr.flatten

  trait FromSide[A] {
    def apply(side: Side): A
  }

  object FromSide {
    implicit object intFromSide extends FromSide[Int] {
      def apply(side: Side) = side.toInt
    }

    implicit object doubleFromSide extends FromSide[Double] {
      def apply(side: Side) = side.toDouble
    }

    implicit object charFromSide extends FromSide[Char] {
      def apply(side: Side) = side.toChar
    }
  }

  /**
   * Converts this board into a 1-D numeric array.  This is likely the 
   * incorrect method signature.
   */
  def flattenNumeric[T: FromSide: Manifest]: Array[T] =
    flatten.map(implicitly[FromSide[T]].apply)
}
```

Now e.g. `board.flattenNumeric[Int]` will compile, but `flattenNumeric[String]` won't.

Note that the `Manifest` part is only necessary because you're using `Array`—if you switch to Scala's own collection types you wouldn't need it.

It's also possible to do this by using manifests or type tags, but that's a quick way to make your program a horrible mess of runtime errors.